# How do I transfer my Firebase Analytics data into BigQuery?

Tags: ios, google-bigquery, analytics, firebase-analytics

I've purchased a Blaze account and set up an integration between my iOS project in Firebase and BigQuery, as directed. But only a Crashlytics table appears in BigQuery, indicating that it's the only data that was transferred. How do I also transfer the Analytics data, which is why I created the integration?

(I recommend readers ignore the downvotes on this question. My question states exactly what my problem is, it states the problem clearly, and I found the one correct answer--that you have to wait for the integration-- and posted it below. I hope this is helpful.)

Comment: why is my question marked with the -1?

Comment: I'm not sure who downvoted - but there's not enough information for anyone to answer this question tho. It might be a bug specific to your account too - try https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: I actually think there was enough information to answer it, and the answer is (see below)

Comment: that's a good answer for anyone that finds themselves in the same problem! (hopefully they'll upvote when they find it!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out it takes time for the Analytics to post to BigQuery. In my case, it took 24 hours. The answer is, I didn't have to do anything: the Analytics data is set up for transfer when your account is integrated, but you'll possibly have to wait a bit for the first transfer.

Comment: I recommend ignoring the downvoters here. This is the correct answer to the question I asked.